# explain var app = express()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to nodejs, I'm wondering where express function is.

express()

Creates an Express application. The express() function is a top-level function exported by the express module.

This the explanation I got from the official website.

But I can only find createApplication() function instead of express() function in the express module after I check the content of express.js.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Hello world example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) in the documentation.

This is the first line:

> ```
> const express = require('express')
> ```

That is where the `express` constant comes from. You define it yourself.

Comment: const express = require('express')   means  I have created an instance of the module.  And it's a variable. But express  in   var app = express()  is a function, I thought they are different.

Comment: @Tony — Functions are first class objects in JavaScript. They can be passed about and stored in variables just like any other kind of object or primitive.

Comment: sorry about that，I may not explain clearly. If I change the code to const express1 = require(‘express’), what happens to app = express(), do I need to change it to express1()? My main question is just like what AngYC said, I don’t know how variable express can be used as a function in var

Comment: Var app = express ()

Comment: @Tony — Yes, if you change the name of `express` then you need to change it everywhere you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean why there aren't any `express()` in the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js). The exported function is named `createApplication()` instead of `express()`.

Module usually export function as a whole so you can name it whatever you want as mentioned by @Quentin, read more about module here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc